# using a static class with properties in php

Tags: php, static

I'm trying to get the selected language to appear in a link with the function `buildMenu()`.

I would like to use it as a static function so I can call it in my header template. If I call the function in the `init()` function it all works fine, however, when I try to use it as a static function, nothing works anymore. I've tried everything I know, so it seems my knowledge of php ends there :)

Any of you got any tips? Thanks in advance!

```
class bootstrap {

    static public $lang;
    static public $class;
    static public $method;

    public function init(){
        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);

        //Set values on startup
        if($url[0] == NULL) {$url[0] = 'nl';}
        if($url[1] == NULL) {$url[1] = 'index';}

        if(isset($url[0])) {$this->lang = $url[0];}
        if(isset($url[1])) {$this->class = $url[1];}
        if(isset($url[2])) {$this->method = $url[2];}        

        $this->loadClass();

    }

    public function loadClass(){

        $filename = 'libs/' . $this->class . '.php';
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            $newController = new $this->class($this->lang, $this->class, $this->method);
            $newView = new view($this->lang, $this->class, $this->method);
        } else {
            $newclass = new error($this->lang, $this->class, $this->method);
        }

    }


    public function buildMenu(){
        echo '<li><a href="http://localhost/testing/' . $this->lang . '/foto">Foto</a></li>';
    }

    /*
     * Set paths
     */

    public static function root(){
        echo "http://localhost/testing/";
    }

}
```

Comment: `self::$lang, self::$class, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **object operator** (`->`) instead of the **scope resolution operator** (`::`) that is used to reference class constants and static properties or methods.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for an explanation of the static keyword and working with static properties.

Update your code to this:

```
class bootstrap{

  static public $lang;
  static public $class;
  static public $method;

  public function init(){
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    //Set values on startup
    if($url[0] == NULL) {$url[0] = 'nl';}
    if($url[1] == NULL) {$url[1] = 'index';}

    if(isset($url[0])) {self::$lang = $url[0];}
    if(isset($url[1])) {self::$class = $url[1];}
    if(isset($url[2])) {self::$method = $url[2];}       

    $this->loadClass();

  }

  public function loadClass(){

    $filename = 'libs/' . self::$class . '.php';
    if(file_exists($filename)){
        $newController = new self::$class(self::$lang, self::$class, self::$method);
        $newView = new view(self::$lang, self::$class, self::$method);
    } else {
        $newclass = new error(self::$lang, self::$class, self::$method);
    }

  }


  public static function buildMenu(){
        echo '<li><a href="http://localhost/testing/' . self::$lang . '/foto">Foto</a></li>';
  }

  public static function root(){
    echo "http://localhost/testing/";
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it give an error on the line of "$newController = new self::lang(self::$lang, self::$class, self::$method);" ?

Comment: Works like a charm, thx! And thx for the info between the object operator and scope resolution operator :)

Answer (score 0):

As @elclanrs has already mentioned, how about changing the `buildMenu()` method to

```
public static function buildMenu(){
    echo '<li><a href="http://localhost/testing/' . self::$lang . '/foto">Foto</a></li>';
}
```

You can then call it using `bootstrap::buildMenu()`.